# Numbered sections in APA6

Tags: sectioning, numbering, apa-style, apa6

I am trying to get automatically numbered sections, subsections, and subsubsections while using the `APA6` format. Is it possible to number sections even though section numbers were deactivated by `APA6`? I would prefer to keep apa6 because apart from section numbers I need to comply with APA. I use overleaf but it does not work with TeXMaker (Windows 10 x64) either.

As you can see below, I tried a numbered list to solve the problem (see comment for the error message). Is there any way to manipulate the APA6 package to get section numbers back?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib,12pt]{apa6}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{Paper}
\shorttitle{Paper}
\author{James Bond}
\affiliation{XXX}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}

\section{\item{1. <- I don't want to do it manually}} % ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

\section{2. <- I don't want to do it manually} 

\end{enumerate}

\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're missing the `secnumdepth` counter. Of course using `enumerate` is a bad idea here ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Section numbers are switched on and off with the counter variable `secnumdepth`, set here to 3, meaning `section`, `subsection` and `subsubsections` should be numbered.

Apparently `secnumdepth` is set to `0` right from the start!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib,12pt]{apa6}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{Paper}
\shorttitle{Paper}
\author{James Bond}
\affiliation{XXX}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\section{Dr. No}

\subsection{Honey Ryder}
\subsubsection{Dr. No again}
\section{Goldfinger} 

\subsection{Thunderball}


%\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This does lead to probably-undesirable consequences like the references section being numbered, and any subsections in appendices being numbered incorrectly. It's probably best to include a `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` just before the `\bibliography` command, to re-set that counter to what apa6 expects.